# Issue with slotLabelInterval and odd time settings

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am trying to change the slotLabelInterval to show a narrow range of time for the days, but it seems to have an issue with using odd intervals. If you use odd intervals 3:30, 4:30, 5:00, 7:00 the first day will be correct, but subsequent days will be off from what they should be for the day. So, if I start with day one at 8:30 with a 3:30 interval, I will get a 12pm and a 3:30pm on the first day. But the second day will start at 9:00am then 12:30pm and 4:00pm and the next day will be 9:30am start, 1:00pm and 4:30pm. But if you give it an even number every thing works fine.

I believe this is a bug in the calculations because it you do the math on the times, each days time is a mulitple of the 3:30 interval. For instance, the last time on day one is 3:30pm + 3:30 + 3:30 + 3:30 + 3:30 + 3:30 = 9am on the next day.

What I am looking for is to confirm this is an issue and possible understand what the solutions for this could be.

[Edit] I am attaching a code snippit and screenshot of the issue. [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG9Fh.jpg)

```
<script>
$(function() { 
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
  now: '{!calCurrentDate}',
  minTime: '08:30',
  maxTime: '17:00',
  slotLabelInterval: '03:30:00',
  slotDuration: '03:30:00',
  snapDuration: '03:30:00',
  slotLabelFormat: ['dddd MMM DD, YYYY','h(:mm)a'],
  slotWidth: '75',
  editable: true, // enable draggable events
  businessHours: false,
  aspectRatio: 2.75,
  scrollTime: '08:00', // undo default 6am scrollTime
```

Comment: can we have some code which can be used to reproduce the issue, please.

Comment: "For instance, the last time on day one is 4:00pm + 3:30 + 3:30 + 3:30 + 3:30 + 3:30 = 9am on the next day.". Sorry but no, that results in: 4pm, 7.30pm, 11pm, 2.30am, 6am, 9.30am. I think you made a miscalculation yourself. Add it up again. Here's your code with the minTime/maxTime removed, so you can see the full set of time intervals generated: http://jsfiddle.net/toytd26b/21/

Comment: Yes, this should have been 3:30pm as the start of the calculation. I have corrected the post. But the point is that given an odd duration the next days intervals are calculating incorrectly. Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: No they aren't. The intervals are spaced every 3-and-a-half hours, continuously. That's what you told it to do. It doesn't reset at midnight each day, if that's what you were expecting. It can't - you'd end up with periods of time which were not part of any slot. And setting minTime/maxTime doesn't change that either, it just hides some of the slots from the view.

Comment: Ok, this is a point of view whether on the expected results of the calculation. From the code perspective it is adding up the numbers, but from and expected result it is incorrect given that the next day starts at 9am rather than 8:30am. To me that is incorrect as it should start at 8:30am on day 2. I would presume with a MinTime and MaxTime this would be the limit on the time calculations for a given day and not have the calculations span multiple days given then result shown. The question comes back is there any way to fix this so that the calculation stays within the time range specified?

Comment: That's the point. The next day starts at midnight, it does **not** start at 8.30am. You just set the "minTime" value to hide everything before 9am. That's purely a **visual** thing, and does not affect the underlying data model of the calendar. It's still possible for there to be slots before 9am and still possible for there to be events in those slots. You just decided not to show them. In theory you could run code during the lifetime of your page which would make those slots visible again. In fact, here's a demo of that: http://jsfiddle.net/toytd26b/26/

Comment: If you want the option to have the calendar re-calculate the slots on a per-day basis, taking into account the min/max time settings, and to pretend the rest of each day doesn't exist, you'd have to submit a feature request to the fullCalendar maintainers - see https://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Requesting-Features/. Or you can write that yourself and submit a patch. As far as I am aware there is no way currently to configure the calendar to do what you're suggesting.

Comment: I understand the calculation point and the minTime and maxTime are just hiding the other times. But the question is how can it be made to work with the issue that I have shown? In other words, if minTime and maxTime will not affect the calculation, what can be done to make the times show properly?

Comment: See my last comment. And anyway, "properly" is an entirely subjective term. The code behaves "properly" in the sense it does what's documented and what (as far as I know) the creators intended. It just doesn't happen to be what you want it to do.

Comment: Thank you for the request feature link, I will look there to post. In the meantime I am also looking for pointers in the code so I could possibly make a change. Understanding this could be complex, it is definitely something that needs to be adjusted for in the application that I am creating.

Comment: I have never worked with the fullCalendar source code, so I can't help you there unfortunately.